# PHP's mail() function doesn't work while using MAMP in OS X 10.8.2

Tags: php, macos, email, mamp

I have searched all the solutions but they don't work out, because my problem is different from others.

I followed the solution step by step according to http://theandystratton.com/2009/fix-phps-mail-function-after-latest-os-x-leopard-update, but when I run the command `tail -f /var/log/mail.log` in terminal, I get an error:

```
sumomomatoMacBook-Pro.local postfix/sendmail[51722]: fatal: chdir /Library/Server/Mail/Data/spool: No such file or directory
```

If you don't understand what I am talking about because of my poor English, you can correct me and ask me for more details.

Comment: Please could you copy and paste the steps from the page into your message so it is available for future reference please?

Comment: Also you can use `backticks` for code highlighting, which makes your post clearer

Comment: @jasdeepkhalsa `Thanks for your advice`. I am new here and I will learn to ask questions clearly soon.

Answer (score 2):

you have to start postfix, this solved my issue
http://benjaminrojas.net/configuring-postfix-to-send-mail-from-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/

Comment: Thank you. But there are something wrong with my Mac, when i use `sudo`, error:`sudo: can't open /private/etc/sudoers: Permission denied`. Maybe I should repair it and try the method you advised later.